# Win 10 crashes at startup with BSOD

Tags: windows-10, bsod, lenovo-laptop

I hope this is the right site and forum for this question.

I have a lenovo laptop with following specs:

- Core i7
- Nvidia GTX 860M
- 8 GB DDR3
- 256 SSD
- Win 10

For some years the laptop used to crash randomly with BSOD specially in hotter days. After it crashed, it won't boot up right away and keep giving me errors like "No bootable media found" and it would never load Windows. However after a while it would boot up and work normally.

I thought there was some heat issue so I opened and cleaned the laptop. Then I also ran disk checks to see if there was any issue there. Nothing found, but it kept doing the random crashes.

Some days ago, it crashed again (it was not hot or anything) with BSOD (I don't remember the error) and when I tried to start it again, it will go to Windows logo and then crash again with BSOD. I kept trying but it always crashed 1-2 sec into Windows logo. Alternatively it would enter the recovery screen but that would also crash with BSOD after couple of seconds.

The BSOD were random as well. Sometime it said something about IRQ, sometimes it was some thread execution, **and sometimes it was no error just that sad smiley sign**. I have seen 3-4 different errors in there. I opened up laptop and **replaced the RAM** but that didn't help. After some tries, it will now not even show the BSOD, it would just flash blue screen for few millisecond and restart.

I took out the hard-drive thinking something is corrupt and attached it as external USB to another laptop. It boot up there without issue and I can use it (although it slow). I also ran check disk on it and it returned no error.

Now what I have is a laptop where

1. Windows installation seems to be fine
2. RAM is replaced
3. Check disk did not return any error
4. It is able to find disk but it just crashes with BSOD within 1-2 sec

So far I haven't been able to find any solution to understand where the problem is. I cannot enter windows and not sure how to enter safe mode without starting windows up. On top of that, as this was second hand laptop, I don't have the BIOS password from previous owner and I have no way to remove it as this one does not have a battery.

I am not sure now where to look for solutions in this case. Everything that I can remove seems to be working fine.

Comment: Post online some of the `.dmp` files that are in folder `C:\Windows\Minidump`. Check the Event Viewer for error messages. Install [temperature monitoring software](https://techguided.com/best-cpu-temperature-monitor-software-windows/) to find out what (if any) component is overheating.

Comment: And mainly : Don't replace parts blindly.

Comment: It seems like your SATA cable might be faulty, or your motherboard might be faulty.

Comment: So yesterday I stared disconnecting each component 1 by 1  (whichever cable I can find i.e. speakers, battery, usb) but still no progress. The one error that I was able to get yesterday (for rest it just flashes BSOD for few millisecond and restart) was IRQL NOT LESS OR EQUAL. I also tried safe mode option, but it failed as well. Seems like something fails right at the start

Comment: @ΞένηΓήινος good suggestion, I will try to replace it.

Comment: @harrymc, I looked the minidump but there were no recent dump. There are few dumps from last years but nothing recent.

Comment: What model is the computer itself and the motherboard? Perhaps the first step should be to remove the BIOS password.

Comment: @harrymc Its Lenovo Y50-70i. I have searched and tried but tbh didnt find anything that helped. There was a cell shaped component stuck on mother board (it was covered in tape so not sure what else is inside) which I removed and kept disconnected for an hour but still the password is there.

Comment: Did you do [this procedure](https://www.4winkey.com/article/reset-lenovo-password.html#4)?

Comment: @harrymc yes. it was similarly packed "thing" that I took out completely from the laptop and left it out for an hour. I even took out the lapop battery. When I started it agian, without any battery, directly connected with power, it sitll asked for password. Not sure if I should keep it out for longer or I have to short circuit something else.

Comment: You will find the latest BIOS version [here](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/lenovo-y-series-laptops/y50-70-notebook-lenovo/downloads/driver-list/component?name=BIOS%2FUEFI) and may attempt to flash it. You may also find trafficked BIOS versions [here](https://www.badcaps.net/forum/showthread.php?t=82963&highlight=Y50-70). I take no responsibility.